# Discor.js - How do I store one number that's not using a data store?

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a counting bot. I need to store a number, and I can't use a variable because if I need to update my bot for restart it all the progress will be lost. I don't want to use a data store, because it's not worth setting up a whole data store for one number. I've tried setting my description to be a number so I could just use that to store the number, but the description has a rate limit so I can only update it once everyone couple minutes using the bot.

[image]

If there is NO possible way to do that, what would be the easiest way to store one variable?
Thanks!

Comment: ... How else would you store the data? There's only RAM and disk. You have two options: using the memory (a variable), or saving it to the disk somehow (persistent data). You can a combination of both, where you save the variable to disk every once in a while, but other than that, you only have two options.

Comment: What would be the easiest way to store a variable that won't reset after my bot resets? Thank you.

Comment: Use a data store. It's pretty easy and does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using a JSON database, super simple to setup and read/write to.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-json-db

```
const JSONdb = require('simple-json-db')
const db = new JSONdb('database.json') // Use whatever path to the json file here. If it doesn't exist it will create a new empty file with that name.

// Set data
db.set('name', 'data') // Sets data with a name, if it already exists it will be overwritten with the new data.
// Read data
db.get('name') // Returns the data associated with the name
// Check data
db.has('name') // Returns true or false if the name exists in the file
// Delete data
db.delete('name') // Deletes data with this name
```